# Objective-C: Drawing 2D Graphics in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, graphics

I don't get how to control and manipulate 2D graphics in Objective-C. I don't mind if the answers say how to use Quartz or just Cocoa. I have this code right now:

```
CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 200, 100 ));
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 0, 1, .5);
CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 100, 200));
```

I got this code from Apple's tutorial on Quartz 2D graphics, but when I invoke the method nothing happens. I'm sure I'm just missing some code somewhere.

I'm working on an OS X app in Xcode with 2D graphics, but the tutorials in the Mac Developer Library aren't very detailed, unless I've been reading all the wrong ones. I'm completely new to drawing in Obj-C so this might seem very basic.

If any other info is necessary, please ask in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling that code? You need to have a graphics context to draw into (i.e. call it inside `drawRect:`)

Comment: Where do I declare this graphics context? In Java you need a JFrame to draw graphics, but where do I declare the window in which I want to draw with Obj-C? I have a method with this code inside it, and this method is invoked with the push of a button.

Comment: You don't create it yourself. You read the current context inside of `drawRect:`. That is the method that will be called when it's time for your view to draw. If you need the view to redraw you call `setNeedsDisplay` on it and that will mark is as dirty so that it get's redrawn.

Comment: What object do I call `setNeedsDisplay` on? The NSWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass NSView, put your drawing code in the method drawRect:
Put a custom view in your UI somewhere and connect it to your subclass in the inspector.

Start with the [Cocoa drawing APi](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). It's easier to begin with and you can get pretty far with that.

If you have a property in your drawing code that you change, you write [self setNeedsDisplay]
in the setter of the property.

Comment: By "custom view" you mean NSWindow or something of the sort right? I'm using Xcode, so I make a new NSWindow in the interface builder and link it to the class itself? Also, if I need to continuously redraw, does that mean I need to put `[myView setNeedsDisplay]` in a while loop?

Comment: You should do some reading, start with [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: you can create a new class (subclass of NSView). In ViewController (where your NSWindow is called) you can add call that class:                        Drawing  *draw = [[Drawing  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:draw];

Answer (score 0):

Your application should have a IUView instance.  Then override drawRect.  Example:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
                           CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 100.0f)];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextRef aRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(aRef, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    aPath.lineWidth = 5.0f;
    [aPath stroke];
}
```

Don't call this method directly; use

```
[self setNeedsDisplay].
```

Comment: the question is about OS X, not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class (subclass of NSView) - "Drawing" in my case ("@interface Drawing : NSView").  In ViewController (where your NSWindow is called) you can call that class:

```
#import "Drawing.h"
<...>
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Drawing  *draw = [[Drawing  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:draw];
<...>
}
```